# BackgroundService doesn't initiate

Tags: android, background-process

I'm trying to initiate a `BackgroundService` but I don't get it running. Here's the Service code:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackgroundData extends Service {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int time;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Called on service created

        time = 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, time); // 1 sec
    }

     private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("OMEGAN...");

                handler.postDelayed(this, time); // 1 sec
            }
        };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here's how I call the service to start:

```
startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundData.class));
```

Which is the problem? This code is from here: http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/running-service-in-background-on.html

I've changed it to use it as I want and it works, but when I implement it to my code, it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you get any errors in the logcat when you start the service? Do you know for certain that your service is not running? Try putting a log statement as the first line in the onCreate() to verify. Also where are you calling startService() from an Activity? A BroadcastReceiver? If it is the latter perhaps the service is fine but the receiver is not receiving correctly.

Comment: Hi @Tim. I'm not getting any error in the logcat and I'm almost sure that the service doesn't initiate because I'm tried what you told me and the `System.out.println("SOMETHING");` doesn't appear in the log... And I'm calling the startService from an Activity.

Comment: Have you declared the service in your manifest file?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Yes, I did it like this `<service
     android:enabled="true"
     android:name=".BackgroundData" />`

Comment: @KrLx_roller `System.out.pringln()` does nothing in Android. LogCat isn't a console. Instead you should produce log messages using the Android `Log` class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: `Log` is not showing anything either... From now on I'll use `Log`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my problem. I was declaring `.BackgroundData` but this file was placed in other package.

I solved changing `.BackgroundData` to `my.own.package.BackgroundData`